# How can I change the foreground color in Assembly?

Tags: assembly, nasm, x86-16, bootloader, bios

I made an OS in Assembly. Now, I want to change the foreground color in Assembly. But I don't know how.

Here is my code:

```
    BITS  16
    ORG 7C00h

start:
    cld
    xor ax, ax
    mov ds, ax
    mov ss, ax
    mov sp, 7C00h

    call print_string
    db 'OS', 0
    jmp $

print_string:
    pop si
    mov bx, 7
    mov ah, 0Eh

.repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je .done
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat

.done:
    jmp si


    times 510-($-$$) db 0
    dw 0xAA55
```

Makefile:

```
DIR=build build
$(shell mkdir -p $(DIR))
$(shell nasm -f bin OS1.asm -o build/OS1.img)
```

How can I change the foreground color in Assembly?

Answer (score 3):

Given that you're launching an OS, there's a big chance that the screen will be in a text video mode. Then the `BL` ForegroundColor parameter won't help much because it's only there for when the screen is in a graphics video mode.

What you can do is let an attribute-aware output function like function 09h, precede the Teletype function 0Eh. You use the 1st function to output the colored character and the 2nd function is there as a convenient way to advance the cursor (which the 1st function doesn't do!).
As a safe-guard, the ASCII codes below 32, including the special characters like 7, 9, 10, and 13 (Beep, Tab, Linefeed, and CarriageReturn), are not sent to the function 09h simply because they are not really characters, are they?

An attribute byte allows you to specify both foreground- and background colors. The low 4 bits encode the foreground color (FGC) and the high 4 bits encode the background color (BGC).

```
                         BGC  FGC
LightRedOnBlack:  0Ch == 0000_1100b   ; 0 is black and 12 is light red
BrighWhiteOnBlue: 1Fh == 0001_1111b   ; 1 is blue and 15 is bright white
...
```

```
print_string:
    pop si
    mov cx, 1      ; RepetitionCount=1
    mov bx, 000Ch  ; DisplayPage=0, Attribute=12 (LightRedOnBlack)
.repeat:
    lodsb
    cmp al, 0
    je  .done
    cmp al, 32
    jb  .skip
    mov ah, 09h    ; BIOS.WriteCharacterAndAttribute
    int 10h
.skip:
    mov ah, 0Eh    ; BIOS.Teletype
    int 10h
    jmp .repeat
.done:
    jmp si
```

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting using the BIOS int 10h function 0Eh.  According to [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INT_10H), that is:

> Teletype output   AH=0Eh  AL = Character, BH = Page Number, BL = Color (only in graphic mode)

so the value in bl (bottom half of bx) specifies the color attribute to use.  You are using 7 (light grey on black).  You can find other colors [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BIOS_color_attributes)